# Mini Akinator - alocar linha por linha arquivo.txt em vetor

Tags: c, array, arquivo

Estou melhorando um código que fiz para um trabalho da faculdade. Uma versão bem simplificada do Akinator. Antes fiz tudo no código principal, agora quero ler os personagens de um arquivo txt. Já criei o arquivo e já preenchi com as opções, só que agora preciso pegar linhas específicas do arquivo para imprimir e manipular no resto do código. Segue o que já fiz.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    FILE *personagens;
    personagens = fopen("personagens.txt", "r");

    //fprintf(personagens,"Son Goku\n"); -> escrever no arquivo

    char modpersonagens[100];

    while(fgets(modpersonagens, 100, personagens) != NULL){
        printf("%s", modpersonagens);
    }
    fclose(personagens);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A sua duvida é como ler varias personagens uma por cada linha do ficheiro?

Comment: Isso, quero colocar cada personagem em um lugar do vetor, para poder manipula-los.

Comment: O arquivo de texto está formatado com palavra \n, palavra \n